# Pickling using protocol 2: Python3->2 data

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to data a data array created in Python3.2, pickle it, and then open it in Python2.7.  However, there is some part of the data that Python2.7 is objecting to, even though on a sample of the data it does fine, and I was wondering how to figure out what was going wrong.

So in Python3.2:

```
import pickle
with open('c:\\test.pickle', mode='wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(t_array, f, 2)
```

Then, when reading in Python2.7:

```
import pickle
f = open('c:\\test.pickle', mode='rb')
t_data = pickle.load(f)
```

The error is:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1217, in load_build
    setstate(state)
TypeError: must be char, not unicode
```

The data is an array of dicts, nested at most two deep, e.g:

```
{'key3': '3', 'key2': 1.1, 'key1': 1, 'dict': {'dkey2': 2, 'dkey1': 1}}
```

What's (probably) going wrong here?  Is there any easy way to see what in the original (large) dataset is causing the problem?

Comment: Can you post a link to a text representation of the data you're dumping (assuming it's representable as text)?

Comment: It's a ~30MB file (while pickled), so I'm not sure how helpful that would be.  It's also part of the reason why I am having some trouble identifying the particular cause of the error...all of the data is representable as text and is pretty similar to the given example, just with more key-value pairs.

Comment: Well, the example works for me (although, of course, the strings come back as Unicode objects). So I really can't tell what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear -- on a few small samples of the data, the procedure works fine.  So that example given works for me too, but the actual data structure (which is much bigger) does not unpickle.  I'll try to play around some more to see if I can find a small example that fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pickle isn't as good as it might look like. Security vulnerabilities and many issues like these.

A much better idea is to create your own save format, for example using json.

Comment: This is what ended up being best.  Security isn't an issue here, and I was able to just use eval() to do most of the work in the end.